# How do I know how close I am to levelling up?

Tags: planet-crashers

There are a few things I have to wait to be a certain level to do (the biggest one being level 5 to leave Lushie Greenie), and I have no idea when I will hit those levels. I am currently level 4, so I know I will hit it eventually, but I would like to have some idea of how much longer it is going to be so I can plan my questing accordingly.

I don't want to do a ton of quests where I will die a lot and waste time if I only need to like kill one or two more guys, but I also don't want to just stick to easy quests and have it take forever.

Is there any way to know how close I am to the next level?

Comment: It's kinda funny that it's hard to find stuff about Planet Crashers on the Internet. To become lvl 5 you need about 1200 xp so just try to get that. I leveled up at 1205 xp so just aim a little higher then 1200. Also if you keep dying in hard dungeons remember you don't always need to fight the person - you can just run around them.

Comment: You need to get 1200 experience to get to level 5.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to see how much xp you need for the next level.